# Switch users issue on MacOS Monterey

Tags: macbook-pro, monterey

After I upgraded my MBP 2017 to Monterey 12.1 I noticed that switching between two Users over UI stopped working stably. Both users are Admin on the MBP. When after a reboot one users logs in and works for a while and then I switch to another user it often happens then I see Rainbow-spin-of-death. The macOS just hangs and I can only move the cursor on the screen. After that I need to reboot to make it work again.

How can I debug or fix the issue?